# MySQL - Replace string if it appears

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I am trying to remove 'total value', 'trophy total value', and 'welfare fund' from the data.

MySQL 8.

Data:

```
1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350;total_value,10000;welfare_fund,200;trophy_total_value,150;
```

Desired output of data:

```
1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350
```

Current code (only removes the words 'total value' etc):

```
SELECT PrizeMoneyBreakDown,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,'total_value',""),'welfare_fund',""),'trophy_total_value',"") as new
FROM race2;
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: You'll have to use [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to remove the keywords and also their following integers. Note that SQL is generally not a convenient language for complex string operations. I suggest just fetching the whole string into the client application and do your string substitution there. It will be easier in virtually any programming language.

Comment: What should i use as client application?

Answer (score 1):

With REGEXP_REPLACE you could do something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350;total_value,10000;welfare_fund,200;trophy_total_value,150;', '(total\_value|welfare\_fund|trophy\_total\_value)[^;]*;', '')
```

IF you are on an older version of mysql, though, this function may not be supported.

Comment: I need to do this for multiple rows though with different data

Comment: You'll need to put that in your question and share sample data so we can help identify the regex pattern that will be needed.